# Memory Dump in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sos, memory-dump, immediate-window

I'm trying to follow this tutorial but with the immediate window in vs2010 rather than WinDBG:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2005/11/25/497016.aspx

but I'm getting stumped by the following:

> Each static is represented by a
>   particular element in this array. So
>   we can find it by searching for it in
>   the memory occupied by the Object[]:
>
> ```
> 0:003> s-d 0 L?0xbfffffff 03651ec4  
> 01cc2fc8  03651ec4 00000500 01cc3008 11000001  ..e......0......
> 02060094  03651ec4 e13989e8 c35e9077 01cc1880  ..e...9.w.^.....
> ```

this "s-d" isn't a part of the sos.dll, so I assume it's either WinDBG or some other extension that dumps the memory at an address.

Is it possible to run this command in the immediate window, or otherwise get the memory dump at an address from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be searching memory for a particular bit pattern, so it would seem to resemble [.S](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171363.aspx)